# Hide a component using selected option in select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

Going to explain what I am trying to do;

**First**,
I make a `foreach` of an object like a house, that has its properties, like a `size` and `numberFamiliars`.

Ok, that `size` has multiplied values like 1,2,3 and 4.
But there is no 1 house, there are 30 houses, that have 4 values each one in the `size` property.

Them on the other side I have a `dropdown select` menu with `Select2 jquery plugin`.

What I am trying to do is when I select one property **in the dropdownSelect2** like size = 4, them all the objects that don't have that property should have the `display: none`. 
How can I bind one to other??, I mean in the select2 I can take the `id` and in the foreach I can make a `data-attribute` to bind one to another but I don´t know how make it possible?

I mean given an id/name to that html element and them and do something like:
`if(select2HousePropertiesSelected === house.hasthatValueinHisPropetie)
{ show } else { hide }`.

So this is what I am trying to do:
I have this `select`:

```
<select class="listboxServices select2-hidden-accessible" id="HotelAvailSideFilterResult_serviciosID" multiple="" name="HotelAvailSideFilterResult.serviciosID" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
<option value="abc">zyz</option>
<option value="cba">xyz</option>

and go on..
</select>
```

Now use this id or this class to make a relation to the selected items on the select
**When there are same elements in the data-listServicios and in the other array them add some css class.** This is what I want

Comment: you can do that with simple js too...

Comment: yeah but its my second day on JS and I need i lttle bit more, can you explain how? The idea is where an option is selected in Select2 where the value is the same as the property displayed, them hide me the other components

Comment: can you please tell me exactly what you want to do so I can help you

Comment: I have a select with options, them in the other side I a have an object with data-attribute with these options, when in the select a option is selected do something with the object that has that options/properties. I am explaining right?

Comment: Hi Qiqke, in order to get a good response on this form, could you please provide us with a simple implementation of your html, this will provide us with a good idea of your code structure.

Comment: On my way! take a look now and let me know!, thank you @qpirate !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with what you have given us, i have drawn up [this](https://jsfiddle.net/dkxp7624/2/) fiddle

what it does is (using the event you have said you use) iterates through the table rows where the `data-listService` attribute contains the code, and then hides it.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('.listboxServices').select2()
        .on('select2:select', (e) =>
        {
            $(this).val().forEach(f=>
            {
                $('tr[data-listServices="'+f+'"]').hide();
            });

        });
});
```

Comment: Oh men you are a monster!!, I made a solution but to much dirty tomorrow I´ll let you know how this works, sure better than mine so congrats! Tomorrow I´ll give you green tick!

Comment: This was a very quick edit, there is probably a better way to get this to work, but should give you an idea on how to get it working

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to show what you select from a select box.

you can do it like this

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  var s = document.getElementById("select");
  var selectedValue = "You Selected: "+s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
  x.innerHTML = selectedValue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select onchange="myFunction()" id="select">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<div id='myDIV'> Select you Choice :-) </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Whatever you'll select will appear there.
you can modify with your needs with minimal changes

Comment: can you explain that? I am using `Select2` with a selectedItem

Comment: you just need the js function I have written and on which element you want to add it as I have done on a text box.

Comment: gonna edit the question please take a look if you have time :)

Comment: if you get your answer make sure you click on Right button on my answer

Comment: I must eat something but looks nice your question let me an hour and I came back to  you

Comment: Hi again, sorry this is not what I am trying to archieve. What I want is when a `selected value ="X" ` = `@model.propertie.propertie` make something. I know how to take the value of a selected item, them compare that value to the value of other if and them make something like add a css rule, you know what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I´ll Explain what I did, but first @Qpirate did it perfect, I just modified a bit that code to look like this:

```js
$('#HotelAvailSideFilterResult_serviciosID').on('select2:select', function (e) {
            var data = e.params.data;
            console.log(data);

            $('tr[data-listServices*="' + data.id + '"]').hide();

        });
$('#HotelAvailSideFilterResult_serviciosID').on('select2: unselect', function (e) {
            var id = ',' + e.params.data.id + ',';
            console.log(id);

            $('tr[data-listServices*=",'+ id+',"]').show();

        });
```

This means when to hide and when to show. Later I´ll post my own solution that is a little dirty but its a start.
The way I did it.... :

not posted yet

But just as a resume this allow you to filter data from two different elements in the html using data-attributes using also `select2` as a dropdownSelectList. I´ll post my answer probably tomorrow